# WebService banguat.gob.gt

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl, xampp

Thank you all in advance for the help:
I have this code:
    `require_once('include/nusoap/lib/nusoap.php');
$soapclient = new soapclient('http://www.banguat.gob.gt/variables/ws/TipoCambio.asmx');
print_r( $soapclient->call( 'TipoCambioDia' ) );`

and gives me this error:Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://www.banguat.gob.gt/variables/ws/TipoCambio.asmx' : Premature end of data in tag html line 3 in C:\xampp\htdocs\cambio_moneda\cambio_moneda.php:3 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\cambio_moneda\cambio_moneda.php(3) : SoapClient->SoapClient('http://www.bang...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\cambio_moneda\cambio_moneda.php on line 3

---

Then I tried with this code:

```
require_once('include/nusoap/lib/nusoap.php');
$soapclient = new soapclient();
$result = $soapclient->call( 'TipoCambioDia' , array(), "http://www.banguat.gob.gt/variables/ws/TipoCambio.asmx?op=TipoCambioDia", "http://www.banguat.gob.gt/variables/ws/TipoCambio.asmx?op=TipoCambioDia");  
print_r( $result );
```

And I get this error results:Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] SoapClient::SoapClient(): Invalid parameters in C:\xampp\htdocs\cambio_moneda\cambio_moneda.php:3 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\cambio_moneda\cambio_moneda.php(3) : SoapClient->SoapClient() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\cambio_moneda\cambio_moneda.php on line 3

What I want to accomplish is to get the exchange rate plus the date and store it in a variable

Thanks to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the fatal error is that the URL you are using to create $soapclient is not a WSDL file. You will need to change it (note the ?WSDL in the URL):

```
$soapclient = new soapclient('http://www.banguat.gob.gt/variables/ws/TipoCambio.asmx?WSDL');
```

Next, to get "TipoCambioDia" call, you need to use it directly, i.e.:

```
$soapclient->TipoCambioDia()
```

Doing this will return in a stdObject:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [TipoCambioDiaResult] => stdClass Object
        (
            [CambioDolar] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [VarDolar] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [fecha] => 30/01/2015
                            [referencia] => 7.65538
                        )

                )

            [TotalItems] => 1
        )

)
```

Comment: Thank you very much @BrianTovar worked perfect
Just one question how did you know the answer? to learn and what to do in other situations

Comment: I opened the URL you were using to instantiate your $soapclient and noticed that it was serving HTML. There is a link on the page for the WSDL.

I then created a simple PHP script to play around with the SOAP service. At first, using $soapclient->call() directly returned an error, so I tried calling that endpoint directly.